# How do I use the OutputStream from a subprocess in Java?

Tags: java, process, io, stream

I create a Process using the ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(group.getExec().split(" "))
        .redirectErrorStream(true));
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Currently I get the InputStream and display it to the console with this:

```
InputStream std_out = process.getInputStream();
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(std_out));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}).start();
```

When I attempt to write anything in the console after the subprocess is started, nothing happens - as expected. How do I enable it so I have an interactive terminal?

**EDIT:** To be more specific, I am trying to write commands and send them to the subprocess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `group.getExec().split(" ")`

This is so fragile. Why not just pass `group.getExec()`? The 'split on whitespace' parsing abilities of that particular mode of use of ProcessBuilder is not great, but it's better than this, at least. Just remove `.split(" ")`.

> `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(std_out));`

Search the web for 'java try with resources' and apply it here; this is leaky.

> `} catch(IOException e) {`
>   `e.printStackTrace();`

That's not how you do exception handling. If you don't want to deal with the issue, the proper "I just do not care" handler is `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`, because that preserves *all* relevant information about the problem *and* ensures that no code executes that is in an unexpected state.

> To be more specific, I am trying to write commands and send them to the subprocess.

Just as there is a `getInputStream()`, method there is also a `getOutputStream()` method. You'd send your commands on this, you can't tie your java process' terminal to the launched subprocess all that easily. You don't need to spin off a separate thread, you can use the thread you are in, though if you want to individually respond to the subprocess exiting, you *would* need 3 threads (one that blocks on the subprocess sending data to your java process - that's the thread you already have, one to wait for the user to type stuff, which sends it to the subprocess once they hit enter, and one to wait until the subprocess exists (`process.waitFor()`)).